# How to select CLOB data type data from db2

Tags: sql, xml, db2

```
SELECT  CAST (ATTCH_BODY AS CLOB(30720))
INTO :WS-ATTCH-BODY
FROM NBASRDOCUM 05  WS-ATTCH-BODY  SQL TYPE IS CLOB(32K).
```

When I am trying to select `clob` data using above query, it shows all zeros (0) in the variable.

Please recommend me how to select `clob` data type. Actually I've inserted a text file with 2k size from GUI into that variable (`ATTCH_BODY`). I need to send it back to GUI using XML strings.

Answer (score 14):

I have done something like the following.

```
select cast(CLOBCOLUMN as varchar(32000)) 
  from TABLENAME where cast(TABLENAME.CLOBCOLUMN as      
   varchar(32000)) like '%AString%' for read only;
```

Comment: Helped me. Thanks

Comment: Hi, what if clob is more than 32000 caracters ?

Comment: It can be useful to rename the column back to it's original name or new name:
select cast(CLOBCOLUMN as varchar(32000)) as CLOBCOLUMN